# How to add a GraphQL server to a pre-existing SQL Database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, graphql

I have created a mySQL database at a Host IP, but now wish to use GraphQL to make queries easier from the front-end. I've know how to set up a GraphQL server from scratch, but was unsure how to access my pre-existing tables at the back-end, and where to define the schema to use them. How would I connect to the database from a GraphQL server?

Prisma was an option I considered, but the service doesn't allow connections to mySQL databases which have pre-existing data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Prisma and other ORMs are a good option if you want a relatively easy/cheap way to expose CRUD operations for your entire database.

If you only need to expose specific aspects of your data or just need to start iterating quickly, you can define your GraphQL API schema at the server level and write resolvers that connect to your database as needed. Your schema does not need to reflect your entire database, but only the data you'd like to expose to clients.

In my experience with GraphQL APIs, I've found that manually writing query schemas and creating resolvers as needed for servicing the client is both faster and easier to maintain for smaller applications.

You can use a SQL client like https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql to interface with your database. The resolvers you write for your schema would then query your database for any data needed to serve the client's request, even if it spans multiple tables.

The GraphQL spec learning site graphql.org has a good description of this process https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

You can try a new open source tool called SwitchQL (github.com/SwitchQL/SwitchQL). I've been working on the project for a while.

You pass it your connection string and it returns everything you need to run a graphql server on top of an existing database. It also returns Apollo compliant client mutation and queries.

We only support Postgres at the moment. If you end up trying it out, please let me know what you think!

Comment: It's more likely a comment to other post

Comment: SwitchQL provides all of the code for the Graphql Server and Client. From there you can modify the code. I think that it's a great way to introduce people to graphql servers that talk to relational databases.